# Marathon show TASK_FAILED Failed to run docker container: Port mappings are only supported for bridge and user-defined networks

Tags: mesos, marathon, mesosphere

After setting 3 controllers to include mesos-master, mesos-slave and zookeeper. Marathon was started in last after 3 services run completed. I found INFO message at Marathon log as below

```
[2017-04-07 15:48:32,291] INFO Acknowledge status update for task service-dev_mysql-serv.a396a075-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004: TASK_FAILED (Failed to run docker container: Port mappings are only supported for bridge and user-defined networks) (mesosphere.marathon.core.task.update.impl.TaskStatusUpdateProcessorImpl:ForkJoinPool-3-worker-13)
```

Start for starting application on Zookeeper.

Zookeeper

```
$sudo docker run -it --net=host --name=zookeeper netflixoss/exhibitor:1.5.2
```

Mesos-master connects to Zookeeper by command line.

```
$sudo docker run -it --net=host \
--name jdb-network-mesos-master \
-e MESOS_PORT=5050 \
-e MESOS_ZK=zk://192.168.1.68:2181/mesos \
-e MESOS_QUORUM=1 \
-e MESOS_REGISTRY=in_memory \
-e MESOS_LOG_DIR=/var/log/mesos \
-e MESOS_WORK_DIR=/var/tmp/mesos \
-v "$(pwd)/log/mesos:/var/log/mesos" \
-v "$(pwd)/tmp/mesos:/var/tmp/mesos" \
-p 15050:5050 \
-p 12181:2181 \
docker.io/mesosphere/mesos-master:1.1.1-rc2
```

Mesos-Slave runing to prepare states for Marathon by specified the resource port `ports:[2000-9000,20000-34000]`.

*MESOS-SALVE

```
$sudo docker run -it --net=host --privileged \
--name jdb-network-mesos-slave \
-e MESOS_PORT=5051 \
-e MESOS_MASTER=zk://192.168.1.68:2181/mesos \
-e MESOS_SWITCH_USER=0 \
-e MESOS_CONTAINERIZERS=docker,mesos \
-e MESOS_LOG_DIR=/var/log/mesos-slave \
-e MESOS_WORK_DIR=/var/tmp/mesos-slave \
-e MESOS_executor_registration_timeout=10mins \
-e MESOS_resources='ports:[2000-9000,20000-34000]' \
-e MESOS_launcher=posix \
-v "$(pwd)/log/mesos-slave:/var/log/mesos" \
-v "$(pwd)/tmp/mesos-slave:/var/tmp/mesos" \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-v /sys:/sys \
-v /cgroup:/cgroup \
-v /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker \
-v /lib64/libdevmapper.so.1.02:/lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02:ro \
-p 25051:5051 \
-p 22181:2181 \
mesosphere/mesos-slave:1.1.1-rc2
```

Application can connect completed between master and slave services. Zookeeper show is normal logs. Marathon run with command line below.

```
$sudo docker run -it \
                 --name jdb-network-marathon \
                 --rm \
                 --net=host \
                 -e MESOS_WORK_DIR=/var/lib/mesos \
                 -p 7070:7070 -p 32181:2181 \
                 --entrypoint=bash mesosphere/marathon:latest-dev
root-marathon(docker-container)$./bin/start \
                 --master zk://192.168.1.68:2181/mesos \
                 --zk zk://192.168.1.68:2181/marathon \
                 --http_port=7070
```

Json for creating container in docker is

```
{
   "id":"/service-dev/mysql-service",
   "cmd":null,
   "cpus":1,
   "mem":512,
   "disk":512,
   "instances":1,
   "container":{
      "docker":{
         "image":"mysql",
         "network":"BRIDGE",
         "portMappings":[
            {
               "containerPort":3306,
               "hostPort":31036,
               "protocol":"tcp",
               "name":null,
               "labels":null
            }
         ]
      },
      "type":"DOCKER"
   }
}
```

Marathon-UI run on port localhost:7070/ui/ show *Delayed* and *Wait* status of application. I attach full message information creates by Marathon is

```
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,563] INFO Computed new deployment plan:
DeploymentPlan id=f210ab3f-c143-4aad-b051-186646b44e26,2017-04-07T15:48:26.558Z
step 1:
Restart(App(/service-dev/mysql-serv, image="mysql"List())))
(mesosphere.marathon.core.group.impl.GroupManagerImpl:ForkJoinPool-3-worker-1)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,582] INFO Deploy plan with force=false:
DeploymentPlan id=f210ab3f-c143-4aad-b051-186646b44e26,2017-04-07T15:48:26.558Z
step 1:
Restart(App(/service-dev/mysql-serv, image="mysql"List())))
(mesosphere.marathon.MarathonSchedulerService:ForkJoinPool-3-worker-39)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,582] INFO Received new deployment plan f210ab3f-c143-4aad-b051-186646b44e26, no conflicts detected (mesosphere.marathon.core.deployment.impl.DeploymentManagerActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,586] INFO Stored new deployment plan f210ab3f-c143-4aad-b051-186646b44e26 (mesosphere.marathon.core.deployment.impl.DeploymentManagerActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-23)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,586] INFO Launching DeploymentActor for f210ab3f-c143-4aad-b051-186646b44e26 (mesosphere.marathon.core.deployment.impl.DeploymentManagerActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-23)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,595] INFO Updated groups/apps/pods according to plan f210ab3f-c143-4aad-b051-186646b44e26 (mesosphere.marathon.core.group.impl.GroupManagerImpl:ForkJoinPool-3-worker-21)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,595] INFO Deployment acknowledged. Waiting to get processed:
DeploymentPlan id=f210ab3f-c143-4aad-b051-186646b44e26,2017-04-07T15:48:26.558Z
step 1:
Restart(App(/service-dev/mysql-serv, image="mysql"List())))
(mesosphere.marathon.core.group.impl.GroupManagerImpl:ForkJoinPool-3-worker-27)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,595] INFO 192.168.1.70 - - [07/Apr/2017:15:48:26 +0000] "PUT //192.168.1.68:7070/v2/apps//service-dev/mysql-serv HTTP/1.1" 200 92 "http://192.168.1.68:7070/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" 4 (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog:qtp731256267-459)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,596] INFO For minimumHealthCapacity 1.0 of /service-dev/mysql-serv leave 1 instances running, maximum capacity 2, killing 0 of 0 running instances immediately. (RunSpec version 2017-04-07T15:48:26.558Z) (mesosphere.marathon.core.deployment.impl.TaskReplaceActor$:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,601] INFO reconcile: found 0 already started instances and 0 old instances (mesosphere.marathon.core.deployment.impl.TaskReplaceActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,602] INFO Reconciling instances during app /service-dev/mysql-serv restart: queuing 1 new instances (mesosphere.marathon.core.deployment.impl.TaskReplaceActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,602] INFO Started instanceLaunchActor for /service-dev/mysql-serv version 2017-04-07T15:48:26.558Z with initial count 1 (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.TaskLauncherActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,603] INFO activating matcher ActorOfferMatcher(Actorakka://marathon/user/launchQueue/1/9-service-dev_mysql-serv#1478068544). (mesosphere.marathon.core.matcher.manager.impl.OfferMatcherManagerActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-25)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,603] INFO Resetting the backoff delay before restarting the runSpec (mesosphere.marathon.core.deployment.impl.TaskReplaceActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-25)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,603] INFO Received offers WANTED notification (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-25)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,603] INFO => revive offers NOW, canceling any scheduled revives (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-25)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,604] INFO 2 further revives still needed. Repeating reviveOffers according to --revive_offers_repetitions 3 (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-25)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,604] INFO => Schedule next revive at 2017-04-07T15:48:31.603Z in 5000 milliseconds, adhering to --min_revive_offers_interval 5000 (ms) (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-25)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,608] INFO No tasks left to launch. Stop receiving offers for /service-dev/mysql-serv, 2017-04-07T15:48:26.558Z (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.TaskLauncherActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-25)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,608] INFO removing matcher ActorOfferMatcher(Actorakka://marathon/user/launchQueue/1/9-service-dev_mysql-serv#1478068544) (mesosphere.marathon.core.matcher.manager.impl.OfferMatcherManagerActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-25)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,608] INFO Received offers NOT WANTED notification, canceling 2 revives (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,608] INFO => Suppress offers NOW (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,609] INFO Finished processing 285ef74b-aaa3-44cf-b650-d687fc6e2923-O156 from dc00cb3b8dbd. Matched 1 ops after 2 passes. ports 2000->9000,20000->31035,31037->34000; cpus 15.0; mem 70771.0; disk 4599.0 left. (mesosphere.marathon.core.matcher.manager.impl.OfferMatcherManagerActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,609] INFO Processing LaunchEphemeral(Instance(instance [service-dev_mysql-serv.marathon-a396a075-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004],AgentInfo(dc00cb3b8dbd,Some(285ef74b-aaa3-44cf-b650-d687fc6e2923-S1),Vector()),InstanceState(Created,2017-04-07T15:48:26.608Z,None,None),Map(task [service-dev_mysql-serv.a396a075-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004] -> LaunchedEphemeral(task [service-dev_mysql-serv.a396a075-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004],2017-04-07T15:48:26.558Z,Status(2017-04-07T15:48:26.608Z,None,None,Created,NetworkInfo(dc00cb3b8dbd,Vector(31036),List())))),2017-04-07T15:48:26.558Z,UnreachableEnabled(300 seconds,600 seconds))) for instance [service-dev_mysql-serv.marathon-a396a075-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004] (mesosphere.marathon.core.launcher.impl.OfferProcessorImpl:ForkJoinPool-3-worker-9)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,735] INFO 192.168.1.70 - - [07/Apr/2017:15:48:26 +0000] "GET //192.168.1.68:7070/v2/apps//service-dev/mysql-serv/versions HTTP/1.1" 200 119 "http://192.168.1.68:7070/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog:qtp731256267-268)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,881] INFO 192.168.1.70 - - [07/Apr/2017:15:48:26 +0000] "GET //192.168.1.68:7070/v2/queue HTTP/1.1" 200 32 "http://192.168.1.68:7070/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog:qtp731256267-226)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,881] INFO 192.168.1.70 - - [07/Apr/2017:15:48:26 +0000] "GET //192.168.1.68:7070/v2/deployments HTTP/1.1" 200 228 "http://192.168.1.68:7070/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog:qtp731256267-483)
[2017-04-07 15:48:26,882] INFO 192.168.1.70 - - [07/Apr/2017:15:48:26 +0000] "GET //192.168.1.68:7070/v2/apps//service-dev/mysql-serv?embed=app.taskStats&embed=app.readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 898 "http://192.168.1.68:7070/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog:qtp731256267-477)
[2017-04-07 15:48:27,061] INFO 192.168.1.70 - - [07/Apr/2017:15:48:27 +0000] "GET //192.168.1.68:7070/v2/apps//service-dev/mysql-serv/versions HTTP/1.1" 200 119 "http://192.168.1.68:7070/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog:qtp731256267-513)
[2017-04-07 15:48:27,062] INFO 192.168.1.70 - - [07/Apr/2017:15:48:27 +0000] "GET //192.168.1.68:7070/v2/apps//service-dev/mysql-serv/versions/2017-04-07T15:48:26.558Z HTTP/1.1" 200 472 "http://192.168.1.68:7070/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog:qtp731256267-498)
[2017-04-07 15:48:31,758] INFO 192.168.1.70 - - [07/Apr/2017:15:48:31 +0000] "GET //192.168.1.68:7070/v2/queue HTTP/1.1" 200 32 "http://192.168.1.68:7070/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog:qtp731256267-226)
[2017-04-07 15:48:31,759] INFO 192.168.1.70 - - [07/Apr/2017:15:48:31 +0000] "GET //192.168.1.68:7070/v2/deployments HTTP/1.1" 200 228 "http://192.168.1.68:7070/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog:qtp731256267-459)
[2017-04-07 15:48:31,759] INFO 192.168.1.70 - - [07/Apr/2017:15:48:31 +0000] "GET //192.168.1.68:7070/v2/apps//service-dev/mysql-serv?embed=app.taskStats&embed=app.readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 898 "http://192.168.1.68:7070/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog:qtp731256267-268)
[2017-04-07 15:48:31,805] INFO 192.168.1.70 - - [07/Apr/2017:15:48:31 +0000] "GET //192.168.1.68:7070/v2/apps//service-dev/mysql-serv/versions/2017-04-07T15:48:26.558Z HTTP/1.1" 200 472 "http://192.168.1.68:7070/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog:qtp731256267-477)
[2017-04-07 15:48:31,808] INFO 192.168.1.70 - - [07/Apr/2017:15:48:31 +0000] "GET //192.168.1.68:7070/v2/apps//service-dev/mysql-serv/versions HTTP/1.1" 200 119 "http://192.168.1.68:7070/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog:qtp731256267-483)
[2017-04-07 15:48:32,285] INFO Received status update for task service-dev_mysql-serv.a396a075-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004: TASK_FAILED (Failed to run docker container: Port mappings are only supported for bridge and user-defined networks) (mesosphere.marathon.MarathonScheduler:Thread-407)
[2017-04-07 15:48:32,287] INFO all tasks of instance [service-dev_mysql-serv.marathon-a396a075-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004] are terminal, requesting to expunge (mesosphere.marathon.core.instance.update.InstanceUpdater$:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16)
[2017-04-07 15:48:32,289] INFO Removed app [/service-dev/mysql-serv] from tracker (mesosphere.marathon.core.task.tracker.InstanceTracker$InstancesBySpec$:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16)
[2017-04-07 15:48:32,290] INFO Increasing delay. Task launch delay for [/service-dev/mysql-serv] changed from [0 milliseconds] to [1 seconds]. (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.RateLimiter$:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19)
[2017-04-07 15:48:32,290] INFO receiveInstanceUpdate: instance [service-dev_mysql-serv.marathon-a396a075-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004] was deleted (Failed) (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.TaskLauncherActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-25)
[2017-04-07 15:48:32,291] INFO initiating a scale check for runSpec [/service-dev/mysql-serv] due to [instance [service-dev_mysql-serv.marathon-a396a075-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004]] Failed (mesosphere.marathon.core.task.update.impl.steps.ScaleAppUpdateStepImpl:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16)
[2017-04-07 15:48:32,291] INFO Acknowledge status update for task service-dev_mysql-serv.a396a075-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004: TASK_FAILED (Failed to run docker container: Port mappings are only supported for bridge and user-defined networks) (mesosphere.marathon.core.task.update.impl.TaskStatusUpdateProcessorImpl:ForkJoinPool-3-worker-13)
[2017-04-07 15:48:32,296] ERROR New instance instance [service-dev_mysql-serv.marathon-a396a075-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004] failed on agent Some(285ef74b-aaa3-44cf-b650-d687fc6e2923-S1) during app /service-dev/mysql-serv restart (mesosphere.marathon.core.deployment.impl.TaskReplaceActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-27)
[2017-04-07 15:48:32,297] INFO Reconciling instances during app /service-dev/mysql-serv restart: queuing 1 new instances (mesosphere.marathon.core.deployment.impl.TaskReplaceActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-27)
[2017-04-07 15:48:32,297] INFO add 1 instances to 0 instances to launch (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.TaskLauncherActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-27)
[2017-04-07 15:48:33,307] INFO activating matcher ActorOfferMatcher(Actorakka://marathon/user/launchQueue/1/9-service-dev_mysql-serv#1478068544). (mesosphere.marathon.core.matcher.manager.impl.OfferMatcherManagerActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10)
[2017-04-07 15:48:33,307] INFO Received offers WANTED notification (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10)
[2017-04-07 15:48:33,307] INFO => revive offers NOW, canceling any scheduled revives (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10)
[2017-04-07 15:48:33,307] INFO 2 further revives still needed. Repeating reviveOffers according to --revive_offers_repetitions 3 (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10)
[2017-04-07 15:48:33,307] INFO => Schedule next revive at 2017-04-07T15:48:38.307Z in 5000 milliseconds, adhering to --min_revive_offers_interval 5000 (ms) (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10)
[2017-04-07 15:48:33,311] INFO No tasks left to launch. Stop receiving offers for /service-dev/mysql-serv, 2017-04-07T15:48:26.558Z (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.TaskLauncherActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7)
[2017-04-07 15:48:33,311] INFO removing matcher ActorOfferMatcher(Actorakka://marathon/user/launchQueue/1/9-service-dev_mysql-serv#1478068544) (mesosphere.marathon.core.matcher.manager.impl.OfferMatcherManagerActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7)
[2017-04-07 15:48:33,311] INFO Received offers NOT WANTED notification, canceling 2 revives (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4)
[2017-04-07 15:48:33,311] INFO => Suppress offers NOW (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4)
[2017-04-07 15:48:33,312] INFO Finished processing 285ef74b-aaa3-44cf-b650-d687fc6e2923-O157 from dc00cb3b8dbd. Matched 1 ops after 2 passes. ports 2000->9000,20000->31035,31037->34000; cpus 15.0; mem 70771.0; disk 4599.0 left. (mesosphere.marathon.core.matcher.manager.impl.OfferMatcherManagerActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4)
[2017-04-07 15:48:33,312] INFO Processing LaunchEphemeral(Instance(instance [service-dev_mysql-serv.marathon-a7956c66-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004],AgentInfo(dc00cb3b8dbd,Some(285ef74b-aaa3-44cf-b650-d687fc6e2923-S1),Vector()),InstanceState(Created,2017-04-07T15:48:33.311Z,None,None),Map(task [service-dev_mysql-serv.a7956c66-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004] -> LaunchedEphemeral(task [service-dev_mysql-serv.a7956c66-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004],2017-04-07T15:48:26.558Z,Status(2017-04-07T15:48:33.311Z,None,None,Created,NetworkInfo(dc00cb3b8dbd,Vector(31036),List())))),2017-04-07T15:48:26.558Z,UnreachableEnabled(300 seconds,600 seconds))) for instance [service-dev_mysql-serv.marathon-a7956c66-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004] (mesosphere.marathon.core.launcher.impl.OfferProcessorImpl:ForkJoinPool-3-worker-31)
[2017-04-07 15:48:36,753] INFO 192.168.1.70 - - [07/Apr/2017:15:48:36 +0000] "GET //192.168.1.68:7070/v2/queue HTTP/1.1" 200 32 "http://192.168.1.68:7070/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog:qtp731256267-498)
[2017-04-07 15:48:36,753] INFO 192.168.1.70 - - [07/Apr/2017:15:48:36 +0000] "GET //192.168.1.68:7070/v2/deployments HTTP/1.1" 200 228 "http://192.168.1.68:7070/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog:qtp731256267-513)
[2017-04-07 15:48:36,754] INFO 192.168.1.70 - - [07/Apr/2017:15:48:36 +0000] "GET //192.168.1.68:7070/v2/apps//service-dev/mysql-serv?embed=app.taskStats&embed=app.readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 891 "http://192.168.1.68:7070/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog:qtp731256267-226)
[2017-04-07 15:48:36,810] INFO 192.168.1.70 - - [07/Apr/2017:15:48:36 +0000] "GET //192.168.1.68:7070/v2/apps//service-dev/mysql-serv/versions HTTP/1.1" 200 119 "http://192.168.1.68:7070/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog:qtp731256267-268)
[2017-04-07 15:48:36,811] INFO 192.168.1.70 - - [07/Apr/2017:15:48:36 +0000] "GET //192.168.1.68:7070/v2/apps//service-dev/mysql-serv/versions/2017-04-07T15:48:26.558Z HTTP/1.1" 200 472 "http://192.168.1.68:7070/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog:qtp731256267-459)
[2017-04-07 15:48:39,015] INFO Received status update for task service-dev_mysql-serv.a7956c66-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004: TASK_FAILED (Failed to run docker container: Port mappings are only supported for bridge and user-defined networks) (mesosphere.marathon.MarathonScheduler:Thread-409)
[2017-04-07 15:48:39,016] INFO all tasks of instance [service-dev_mysql-serv.marathon-a7956c66-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004] are terminal, requesting to expunge (mesosphere.marathon.core.instance.update.InstanceUpdater$:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16)
[2017-04-07 15:48:39,018] INFO Removed app [/service-dev/mysql-serv] from tracker (mesosphere.marathon.core.task.tracker.InstanceTracker$InstancesBySpec$:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4)
[2017-04-07 15:48:39,018] INFO Increasing delay. Task launch delay for [/service-dev/mysql-serv] changed from [-728 milliseconds] to [1 seconds 150 milliseconds]. (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.RateLimiter$:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16)
[2017-04-07 15:48:39,019] INFO receiveInstanceUpdate: instance [service-dev_mysql-serv.marathon-a7956c66-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004] was deleted (Failed) (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.TaskLauncherActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16)
[2017-04-07 15:48:39,019] ERROR New instance instance [service-dev_mysql-serv.marathon-a7956c66-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004] failed on agent Some(285ef74b-aaa3-44cf-b650-d687fc6e2923-S1) during app /service-dev/mysql-serv restart (mesosphere.marathon.core.deployment.impl.TaskReplaceActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16)
[2017-04-07 15:48:39,019] INFO Reconciling instances during app /service-dev/mysql-serv restart: queuing 1 new instances (mesosphere.marathon.core.deployment.impl.TaskReplaceActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16)
[2017-04-07 15:48:39,019] INFO initiating a scale check for runSpec [/service-dev/mysql-serv] due to [instance [service-dev_mysql-serv.marathon-a7956c66-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004]] Failed (mesosphere.marathon.core.task.update.impl.steps.ScaleAppUpdateStepImpl:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-23)
[2017-04-07 15:48:39,019] INFO add 1 instances to 0 instances to launch (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.TaskLauncherActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4)
[2017-04-07 15:48:39,019] INFO Acknowledge status update for task service-dev_mysql-serv.a7956c66-1ba9-11e7-ab7a-0242ac120004: TASK_FAILED (Failed to run docker container: Port mappings are only supported for bridge and user-defined networks) (mesosphere.marathon.core.task.update.impl.TaskStatusUpdateProcessorImpl:ForkJoinPool-3-worker-1)
[2017-04-07 15:48:40,187] INFO activating matcher ActorOfferMatcher(Actorakka://marathon/user/launchQueue/1/9-service-dev_mysql-serv#1478068544). (mesosphere.marathon.core.matcher.manager.impl.OfferMatcherManagerActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10)
[2017-04-07 15:48:40,187] INFO Received offers WANTED notification (mesosphere.marathon.core.flo
```

Mesos-slave still run in port ranges `-e MESOS_resources='ports:[2000-9000,20000-34000]'`. JSON define container port 3306 and host port is 31036. It's stay on ranges of port specific number. **What's error meaning in**: *"Port mappings are only supported for bridge and user-defined networks"*?

Comment: Mentioned error comes from [Mesos](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/src/docker/docker.cpp#L730-L734). It's weird becouse it should occures only when network is host or none. Can you attach logs from Mesos?

Comment: [MARATHON-7203](https://jira.mesosphere.com/projects/MARATHON/issues/MARATHON-7203)

Comment: Latest build in master branch supports the BRIDGE network modes. I think Mesos cannot use port mapping because the source code hasn't built by the flag --with-network-isolator. See more at link http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/port-mapping-isolator/

Comment: You are partially right. Indeed some kind of isolator is required for port mapping but docker containerizer handle this with docker networks. See more [here](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/c56ce2469602226ce9b8758431da409b98f4efc17d46d58fbd51a149@<user.mesos.apache.org>)